# \citet author coming out blank?

Tags: natbib, amsart, amsrefs

Somehow, my \citet citations are failing to show the author name. I can't quite figure out what I've done wrong... all I can guess is that I've run into an issue between amsart and natbib. I've tried removing amsrefs, and just get several errors regarding definition of environments (bibdiv, biblist) and commands (\bib).

As a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
A textual citation follows: \citet{reference}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{minimalExample}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with minimalExample.bib:

```
@article{reference,
author = {Author, An},
title = {A title},
journal = {A Journal},
year = {2015},
volume = {1},
number = {1},
pages = {1--2},
}
```

The result comes out looking like: "A textual citation follows: , 1]." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `numbers`option of `natbib`

Comment: @Denis Believe it or not, that makes it worse: the result is "A textual citation follows: ."

Comment: My mistake. Try also removing the `\usepackage{amrefs}` line.

Comment: @Denis As stated in the question, it then fails to compile, spitting out various errors, including "Environment bibdev undefined", "Environment biblist undefined", and "Undefined control sequence: \bib".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the following code works well:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{reference,
author = {Author, An},
title = {A title},
journal = {A Journal},
year = {2015},
volume = {1},
number = {1},
pages = {1--2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
A textual citation follows: \citet{reference}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do not forget to delete temporary files when playing around removing packages.

Comment: It miraculously seems to have started working after I changed it at your advice, though I'd have sworn I'd tried this already. Also could have sworn I'd tried this in a clean environment... Ah well. Thanks very much!